# Fixed position of scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-position

This is my example code:

```
<div class="menu">
  menu
</div>

<div class="main">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And css:

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;

height: 300px;
}

.main {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

I wonder if it is possible, to make vertical scrollbar with fixed position (always at the bottom of viewport, so you don't have to scroll whole content down to scroll from left to right).

My fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/uyreeqpd/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of fixing scrollbar position you should give `height:100vh;` to your table and add `oveflow-y:scroll;`.

That way you'll always be able to see the horizontal scroll at the bottom of your table.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uyreeqpd/2/).

```css
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
}

.main {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height:100vh;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  menu
</div>

<div class="main">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, it works, but what if I have div over the table, like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/ozhbuxum/

Comment: well you can do it as you did in this fiddle otherwise you'd have to you use javascript for your original idea of moving the vertical scroll bar to the bottom, and it may feel a bit irritating to the user, not being able to see the content at the top first.

Comment: or you should add a link poiting to the bottom. try this:  https://jsfiddle.net/ozhbuxum/2/

Comment: please reply if it helps or you want to work on your original idea with javascript. I'll be happy to help.